# How to automatically run a Rails command after Heroku successfully deploys?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

Is there a way to run Rails commands after an app has successfully been deployed to Heroku? For example, I currently need to make sure I run `heroku run rake db:migrate --app <app-name>` after each deploy in order to run any necessary migrations. It would be great if this could be automated and ran each time my app successfully deploys to Heroku.

Comment: Have you read e.g. https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/release-phase?

Answer (score 0):

You need an app.json.

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/app-json-schema#scripts

```
{
  "scripts": {
    "postdeploy": "bundle exec rake bootstrap",
    "pr-predestroy": "bundle exec rake cleanup",
  }
}
```

With app.json you can get a [Heroku Button](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-button) that makes deployment for less tech-savvy people easier since you don't need to use the Heroku CLI or even git.